# Puppet provider prefetch

Tags: ruby, puppet, provider

I am writing a provider to generate self signed certificate using the certdog krestfield API.

I have implemented the create, destroy, exists? method and I can properly manage my certificate by making different call to the API.

I implemented puppet resource using the self.prefetch and self.instances methods. I can retrieve the properties of my resources to be aware of their current state.

My resource contain two sensitive types 'username' and 'password' who are required to make the API calls. I can't store those values on the filesystem and I want the 'puppet resource' command to ignore those types.

Currently when I run 'puppet apply' for the manifest:

```
certdog_certificate { 'tstpuppet':
  ensure        => present,
  server        => 'apiserver',
  username      => 'apiserver_username',
  password      => 'apiserver_password',
}
```

It returns:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Certdog_certificate[tstpuppet]/username:  defined 'username' as 'apiserver_username'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Certdog_certificate[tstpuppet]/password:  defined 'password' as 'apiserver_password'
```

Is there a way to hide sensitive types for puppet resources ? How should I process ?

Comment: Configurable data that a provider uses to perform its work but that are not part of the persistent state of a resource are *parameters* as opposed to *properties*.  Both are specified the same way in your resource declarations, but they are defined differently in your custom type code.  If the username and password cannot be recorded on client systems then they should be parameters, and, moreover, your prefetch code should not set values for them (indeed, should be unable to do so).

Comment: Additional details depend somewhat on what version of Puppet you are using, and would benefit from a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I had to properly define my resource attributes.

The configurable data not part of the persistant state should be parameters as describe in the [puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/custom_types.html).

The attributes `username` and `password` are now define with `newparam` instead of `newproperty` as below.

```rb
module Puppet
  Type.newtype(:certdog_certificate) do

    @doc = 'Manage certificate using certdog REST API'

    ensurable do
      desc 'Create or remove a certificate'

      newvalue(:present) do
        provider.create
      end

      newvalue(:absent) do
        provider.destroy
      end

      defaultto :present
    end

    newparam(:cert_name, namevar: true) do
      desc 'Name of the certificate request'
    end

    newparam(:username) do
      desc 'Username for Certdog API server'
    end

    newparam(:password) do
      desc 'Password for Certdog API server'
    end

    newproperty(:server) do
      desc 'Certdog API server address'
    end
end
```

@john-bollinger Thanks for your explanation, I was missing an important concept of the custom types.